# I can't play mp3's with Rhythmbox from my Dropbox folder

Tags: 15.04, rhythmbox

When I try to import or open mp3's from my Dropbox folder using Rhythmbox nothing happens. I'm using Rhythmbox 3.2.1 and Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit. If I copy them to the desktop then they play, but my playlists are inside Dropbox, so I can share them between my devices. OGG files seem to work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Check the permission on your Dropbox folder.  More than likely the do not have the **execute** permission enabled.

<kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open **Terminal**

Enter

```
chmod ug+rwx ~/Dropbox
```

This will enable execution of files in the folder for your application.

Then, close Terminal and re-try your files with **Rhythmbox**.

Alternatively, you can open Nautilus and navigate to your **Dropbox** foler.

Right-click the mp3 file, click **Properties**, the select the **Permissions** tab.  Be sure all users and groups have **Read and Write**
Access.

Comment: I'm still unable to play them. When I try to open them with Rhythmbox mouse pointer goes into loading animation, there is about 20 seconds loading and after that nothing happens and it returns back to pointer.

Comment: Are they on your computer or from the Dropbox website?

Comment: They are in /home/user/Dropbox.
I made a link to this folder on the Desktop and when I tried importing from there it worked.

Comment: Can you post the permissions shown on the mp3 file?

Comment: See the alternate method, I just added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Here is a screenshot [link](http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/CC/3A/e22fa966f452cc3a.jpg)
I tried changing Others to read and write but there is no effect.

Comment: I have changed the chmod command in the answer. Please run that command then re-post the ls -l output again.

Comment: @A.B. Please explain, so I don't make the mistake again.

Comment: It is a security risk and absolutely not necessary to give the world access to this folder (`o+rwx`).

Comment: @A.B. - Edited with correct chmod command, thanks A.B.

Comment: No =) see my edit.

Comment: Guys, using chmod ugo+rwx or ug doesn't work. As I said, ogg files are working fine, it's only mp3's, so I guess it's not a permission problem. Right now the only way is to make a link from the Dropbox folder to the Desktop or somewhere else and import music from there, but why should I do this link in the first place?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply download your mp3's to your Music folder?